# Do input if object is in a set range

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Left : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float playerSpeed = 8;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(0, playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(0, -playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

How can i do it that the if statements only happen if the gameobject with this script is under y=7 and above y=-7?

Comment: y=7 and y=-7 are coordinats sorry if i didn't make this clear

Comment: Add another `if` around those two statement that checks the precondition.

Comment: @RetiredNinja First of all, thanks for the quick answer. Do you have an article about preconditions? I found this one (https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ai.planner@0.1/api/Unity.AI.Planner.DomainLanguage.TraitBased.ICustomPrecondition-1.html) but i dont know if its the right thing

Comment: A precondition is just something to check before doing something else, like `if (transform.position.y >= -7 && transform.position.y <= 7) { /*movement code*/ }`

Comment: @RetiredNinja I actually didnt know you can read the y coordinate with transform.position.y. This fixed my problem thanks mate